# VBA - Excel Chart export Image to Sharepoint folder

Tags: excel, vba

odd issues i'm running into..
When i use the normal .export i get an error around the export method.. and when i use the below everything saves correctly, however it comes out as a PDF instead of a PNG file.. Ideas?

```
    Sub ExportChart()
        Dim objChrt As ChartObject
        Dim myFileName As String
    
        Set objChrt = Sheets("Sheet2").ChartObjects(1)
        myFileName = "myChart.png"
    
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        objChrt.Chart.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePNG, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
        
        MsgBox "OK"
    End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfixedformattype only PDF and XPS are valid formats.  Likely you don't have `Option Explicit` in your module, so the undeclared constant `xlTypePNG` defaults its value to 0, which is the same as `xlTypePDF`

Comment: Tim is correct.  The _chart object itself_ has an option to export to an image, which I am a bit rusty on but I believe I've used PNGs from this in the past.

Comment: Short of syncing the SP folder to your local machine and saving the image file to the local folder, I don't think you have an easy solution to this.

Comment: Tim, thank you for being so helpful. My original goal was to embed a dynamic excel chart (from my sharepoint online folder) onto my sharepoint site - simple but didnt show the chart correctly. Then i tried MS Graph API to copy an image of the chart, which had the same problem. Then i went to using VBA (above). I suppose ill sync the sharepoint to my local and copy the image to a folder.. then automate the picture file to be overridden daily... then automate it being uploaded to my sharepoint site....? any ideas/advice?

Comment: If you have a synced local folder then any updates should automatically get pushed to SharePoint...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ExportAsFixedFormat is the method you use to export the entire spreadsheet with 0 being a PDF and 1 being to XPS.

I believe you'd want to use the [Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.export) method.

`objChrt.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, FilterName:="PNG"`

Comment: ...but I'm guessing that won't work with an HTTP[s} path.

Comment: Confirmed - only work with "regular" (local/network) paths.

Comment: @TimWilliams that is correct.  The transfer to SharePoint would have to happen after this step.